# How do I upload files directly to s3 with rails active storage and vuejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, vue.js, webpacker

I am trying to upload a file to s3 using direct upload s3. I am using rails 5.2 with active storage. Active storage guide only specifies the upload using built in rails views. How do I accomplish the same in frontend js framework such as vue

Rails view version

```
<%= form.file_field :attachment, direct_upload: true %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by manually adding the attributes

```
<input id="video" name="attachment" type="file" data-direct-upload-url="/rails/active_storage/direct_uploads" direct_upload="true" />
```